# Discrepancy with "count(distinct(field))" statement in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, distinct

I'm running a query in SQL Server to count the number of unique email addresses that exist in our database by Australian State. However, when I try to reconcile the numbers to make sure they are right I've noticed a discrepancy which makes me think my query isn't right. Here are the queries I'm using to reconcile the numbers and the actual results:

```
/** Count the total number of active members (status=1) since last night **/
SELECT count(distinct(email)) Total FROM [member] WHERE status = 1 
AND (created_datetime <= '2013-01-11' OR created_datetime IS NULL)
/** RESULT: 8958 **/

/** Count the number of active members (status=1) who live in Victoria since last night **/
SELECT count(distinct(email)) Total FROM [member] WHERE status = 1 
AND (created_datetime <= '2013-01-11' OR created_datetime IS NULL)
AND [state] = 'vic'
/** RESULT: 7545 **/

/** Count the number of active members (status=1) who don't live in Victoria since last night **/
SELECT count(distinct(email)) Total FROM [member] WHERE status = 1 
AND (created_datetime <= '2013-01-11' OR created_datetime IS NULL)
AND [state] <> 'vic'
/** RESULT:1446 **/

/** Add the two results to see how they compare to the total **/
SELECT 7545+1446
/** RESULT:8991 **/
```

You'll notice that the total number of distinct emails is 8958, but if you add those that live in Victoria and those that don't live in Victoria the number is 8991 which is different. Am I using the count distinct function wrongly?

Comment: `<= '2013-01-10 23:59:59'` - so you don't want to include any that occurred *during* the last second of the day? It's almost always better (with date queries) to use exclusive end points for periods - e.g. `< '20130111'`.

Comment: Good point. I've updated the query and I'll edit my question above

Answer (score 2):

The created_datetime in the where clause is different. In the first query it is

```
WHERE status = 1 
AND (created_datetime <= '2013-01-10 23:59:59' OR created_datetime IS NULL)
```

for the other two queries it is

```
WHERE status = 1 
AND (created_datetime <= '2013-01-31 00:00:00' OR created_datetime IS NULL)
AND [state] <> 'vic'
```

Raj

Comment: Good spot. I've updated the query and amended my question. However the results are the same (mainly because both dates were in the future when I wrote the question)

Answer (score 2):

On top of the answers provided by @Raj and @MarkD, I want to add another observation.
Shouldn't the

```
OR created_datetime IS NULL
```

be in only one of the statements and not both? If it is in both, there will be duplicates and the result of the "total" query will never match the sum of the individual queries.

Comment: @oragecrush is right to me, coz on all the query we are getting repeatation of created_datetime = NULL

Comment: Ok so I tried running the test again twice - removing "OR created_datetime IS NULL" from the "who lives in Victoria" query in one test, and removing the same statement from the "who doesn't live in Victoria" query in the second and the numbers still don't add up unfortunately.

Comment: One thing to note... If I remove `OR created_datetime IS NULL` from all of the queries and run the test, the numbers add up. But I guess this isn't much use to me as it ignores a massive subset of my users

Comment: There might be duplicate emails? If the same email has been entered for a member from 'vic' and one for another state, then there are bound to be duplicates. If the point of the exercise is to tally the individual counts against the total, why don't you remove the `distinct` and count the whole email list? That should give you a match.

Comment: In theory any duplicate members should reside in the same state, but I can't guarantee this. There are definitely duplicate emails. The main point of the exercise is to compile a report that shows the number of unique members, and then all breakdowns (by state, then gender, then age) should all tally up to this total. But at the moment they don't, so I compiled the example above just to demonstrate this on the web. I'm at a bit of a loss about what to do

Answer (score 2):

You are counting **distinct** emails. If a user from Victoria has an email identical to that of a user from elsewhere, those would count as 1 in the total count.

When counting Victoria and non-Victoria emails separately, both would again count as 1 in each case, giving you the total of 2 (if you dare to add them up), which would be the very discrepancy you are having now.

Comment: I think this is a very valid point Andriy. Is there any way to show the following then: A total of all users (from all states, or those with no state), then a breakdown of users in each state (with a separate column for those with no state)? The total should be reconcile to the sum of the breakdown

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `SELECT state, COUNT(*) FROM member GROUP BY state`?

Answer (score 1):

The balance of your `[State]`s might be `NULL`
And as Raj points out, the `DATETIME` on your queries differs.

```
SELECT count(distinct(email)) Total FROM [member] WHERE status = 1 
AND (created_datetime <= '2013-01-31 00:00:00' OR created_datetime IS NULL)
AND [state] IS NULL
```

Comment: If I run `SELECT count(distinct(email)) Total FROM [Staging-vPowerClub].[dbo].[member] WHERE AND [state] IS NULL` it returns 0 results, so all entries have an associated [state]